# Display two hyperlinks in one line

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to display two hyperlinks using anchor tags. I have the following code to display hyperlinks

```
<li>
    <a href="link1"><h4>link1</h4></a> & 
    <a href="link2"><h4>link2</h4></a>
</li>
```

but the links are displayed like

```
link1
& 
link2
```

how can i display the links like this

```
link1 & link2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `<h4>` tag or set the css style: `h4 {display:inline}`

Answer (score 2):

Make `h4` inline too!

```
li a{display:inline-block}
li a h4{display:inline-block}
```

Answer (score 2):

just change the css of ur a tag

```
a{display:inline-block;}
```

or make use of inline css

```
a style="display:inline-block;" href=""
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your css>>>

```
li a, li a h4 {
display:inline-block
}
```

make the elements inline to accomplish your request

please comment back if you need more help

Comment: instead you can put as li a, li a h4{display:inline-block}

Comment: @PravinVaichal thats's right, I didn't do that because i was typing fast - I will change it now. thanks

Comment: Yea sometimes it happens